# Why use these many macros when it is really not needed

Tags: c++, stl, std

When we look at STL header files, we see many macros used where we could instead write single lines, or sometimes single word, directly. I don't understand why people use so many macros. e.g.

```
 _STD_BEGIN

using ::type_info;

 _STD_END


 #if defined(__cplusplus)
  #define _STD_BEGIN    namespace std {
  #define _STD_END      }
  #define _STD  ::std::
```

Comment: I'd guess they come from an era when the compiler wouldn't necessarily support namespaces.

Comment: Because it's conditionally defined...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Library providers have to cope with a wide range of implementations and use case.  I can see two reasons for use of macros in this case (and there are probably others I'm not thinking about now):

- the need to support compilers which don't support namespace.  I'm not sure if it would be a concern for a recent implementation, but most of them have a long history and removing such macros even if compilers which don't support namespaces are no more supported (the not protected `using ::type_info;` hints that it is the case) would have a low priority.
- the desire to allow customers to use their implementation of the standard library in addition to the one provided by the compiler provider without replacing it.  Configuring of the library would then allow to substitute another name for `std`.

Answer (score 4):

That

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
```

in your sample is the key. Further down in your source I would expect to see alternative definitions for the macros. Depending on compilation environment, some constructs may require different syntax or not be supported at all; so we write code once, using macros for such constructs, and arrange for the macros to be defined appropriately depending on what is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Macros vs variables : macros can run faster in this case because they are actually made constants after pre-processing.(Operations on constants are faster than that on variables).

Macros vs functions : Using macros avoids the overhead compared to that when using functions requires pushing parameters to stack, pushing return address and then popping from stack....

Macros : Faster execution but requires more memory space. 
Function : Slower execution but less memory space.

Comment: Just wrong. The variable [sic] would of course be declared `const` and then it's just as fact as a literal. Functions defined in headers are `inline` (to avoid the ODR). Therefore when comparing macros and functions you can't state that functions have overhead. Similarly, you can't say that functions take less memory space.